# Can't access phpmyadmin

Tags: centos, vps, forbidden

I tried to update my phpmyadmin to the newest version but now I get this error message when I try to access it:

> Forbidden
>
> You do not have permission to access
>   this document.

I have a vps hosting with centos. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the new phpMyAdmin directory has the wrong permissions. Try:

```
chown -R apache:apache /home/somewhere/phpMyAdmin
```

Obviously substitute in the appropriate path to phpMyAdmin. Also check what user Apache is using (could be apache, nobody, www, www-data, etc...).

Comment: Tried to run the command but nothing happened!

Comment: If it worked nothing will appear to have happened. Look at the directory to see if the ownership has changed (`ls -al /somewhere/phpMyAdmin`).

Comment: It could be wrong permissions, but it could also be other cases. You should look at the error logs, like @ooshro suggests.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to look the logs. In CentOS Apache write log in /var/log/httpd/.

If "/home/somewhere/phpMyAdmin" is symlink, add "Options FollowSymlinks" inside ...